# Facebook Send Dialog return error 500 when user already logged in

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to implement Facebook Send Dialog, but I have got some problems with it.

### **Implementation via link** *(prefered)*

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?
  app_id=123456789
  &link=http://www.mypage.com/blahblah/blahblah
  &redirect_uri=http://www.mypage.com/blahblah/blahblah
```

This works fine, but only when you not logged to facebook. So as first, you are redirected to FB login page and when you will log in, then you will be able to send the link. All works fine.

But when u already logged in Facebook, then you are redirected to Facebook and you can see ERROR 500.

URLs of my web are set in my **FB App settings -> basic -> App Domains** ofc.

### **Implementation via Facebook SDK**

This works fine in both of cases, but it can be rendered only as `popup` dialog and I need something like `target="_blank"` (new browser window) and I think, that it is not possible to achieve this via FB SDK.

Do you have any tips, how to solve problem above?
Thank you very much.

Comment: File a bug report and ask them to fix the issue you are seeing with the redirect version? https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/